# Jhipster Elasticsearch org.elasticsearch.indices.IndexMissingException

Tags: jhipster

I am trying out **jhipster** and learning the technology stack.

Environment:
Database:

- Orcale (both prod and dev)
- Elasticsearch
- Windows

I created a new jhipster project and copied some external generated entities into the domain folder.

Then wrote a parser that generates the [Entity].json file in the **.jhipster** folder.

I ran the entity subgenerator using this json file which asks me to overwrite the existing entity file(which I copied from external project).

I select no and then the generator generates the CRUD html/js files.

When I run the application, it can save/edit data correctly.

But when I search, I get **IndexMissingException**.

I checked the target folder and found that **target/elasticsearch/data** does not contain any index for this entity.

I am not very familiar with elasticsearch and would like to know if there is any workaround for this IndexMissingException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this.

You can simply delete your target folder while the application isn't running, then rerun it. This will regenerate the indexes for all of your entities, but because Elasticsearch is essentially a data store, you will **lose all data** from it so it is not appropriate for a production environment.

I have created a [Yeoman generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer) that will generate a service to reinsert all data from your main datastore into your elasticsearch indexes. This can help resolve the data issue from the first solution. It will also programmatically delete and recreate your indexes, so it can be used to solve your problem directly.

You can use the [Create Index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch//reference/current/indices-create-index.html) while the server is running. This is important for a production environment where the data in your index is important to keep.

Comment: Thanks geraldhumphries for your reply. I will try out with your generator and inform

Comment: Tried with your solution. Seems to work. The IndexMissingException is reslved now. Thanks